# How to get a value from an array of objects in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It is necessary to get values ​​from an array of objects and display them on the screen. Now I get an error in the console: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
It also says in the console: The above error occurred in the  component. How can this problem be solved?

ListItem.js:

```js
const ListItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{props}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ListItem;
```

List.js:

```js
import ListItem from "./ListItem/ListItem";

const listObj = [
  {
    title: "House 1",
  },
  {
    title: "House 2",
  },
  {
    title: "House 3",
  },
];

function HouseList() {
  return listObj.map((house, index) => {
    return <ListItem key={index} title={house.title} />;
  });
}

const List = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "50%" }}>
      <HouseList />
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Comment: `props.title` instead of just `props` in the `h2` element.

Comment: Probably a typo `props.title` instead of `props` in `ListItem` JSX.

Comment: In your example, it would not make a lot of sense, as `ListItem` has a single prop (apart from `key`), so you could simply do: `<h2>{props.title}</h2>`. Anyway, if you have to display all the props and _none of your props values is an object_, you simply do the same thing you have done for `HouseList`: `{Object.values(props).map(prop => <h2>prop</h2>)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use {props.title} instead of only props. Here is the [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-stitch-2k1515?file=/src/App.js)

The props would be everything so you should give the absolute object path.

props={title:"React", version:18} so if you call just {props}, you will get {title:"React", version:18} so you should define {props.title} {props.version}

Plus, you can level up your knowledge about props just by reading this React official doc
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

```
const ListItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{props.title}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply we can use :-

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))

Comment: I also thought that `JSON.stringify(obj)` was the solution at first, but if you look closer at the issue you'll notice that it's actually about `props` being used directly, instead of using `props.title`. Your answer is unfortunately incorrect.